# Telegram update consuming

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm new to `Telegram Bots API` so I'm still at abstraction phase.
Anyway I'm testing some Telegram methods using `Postman`. When I send a `getUpdates` request to server, it sends me all the updates, but the problem is if I send `getUpdates` again, I receive previous updates, too.
So is there any way to consume incoming updates so that server doesn't send them again?
`Telegram Bots API` is very compact and lacks good explanations. That's why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from Telegram's [Bots FAQ](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#long-polling-gives-me-the-same-updates-again-and-again):

> The `getUpdates` method returns the earliest 100 unconfirmed updates. To confirm an update, use the offset parameter when calling getUpdates like this:
>
> ```
> offset = update_id of last processed update + 1
> ```
>
> All updates with update_id less than or equal to offset will be marked
>   as confirmed on the server and will no longer be returned.